# LWP is same as libwww-perl?

Tags: perl, perl-module

I use the [CPAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPAN) tool to install [LWP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_for_WWW_in_Perl), and it failed. Then I used the PPM tool. I can't find LWP in PPM, but only `libwww-perl` (LWP). Are they the same with a different name?

I am using [Strawberry Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strawberry_Perl).

Comment: I think LWP comes bundled with Strawberry Perl, you shouldn't have to install it.  Try running: perl -MLWP -E "say 'ok'" to see if it is there or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, they are more-or-less the same thing.
[`libwww-perl`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/) is the name of the distribution, and [`LWP`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP) is the name of the main module in that distribution. So in order to use `LWP`, you would install the `libwww-perl` distribution. Make sense?

Comment: Well, [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP::UserAgent) is really the primary module.  [LWP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP) just contains documentation; you wouldn't use it in a program.

Comment: @cjm, Well, it loads most of the modules of the distro, so some people `use` it for that reason.

Comment: @ikegami, if you look at `LWP.pm`, the only thing it does (aside from declaring a version number) is `require LWP::UserAgent;`.  You might as well skip the middleman.